# Amazon SQS Callback not being called on 1.9.x for the async client when receiving

Tags: java, amazon-sqs

I'm trying to get sqs working on receiving messages, but I ran in to an issue. I'm using 1.9.40 of the sdk, and Java 8 and when I make the following call:

```
ReceiveMessageRequest request = new ReceiveMessageRequest(queueName).withMaxNumberOfMessages(10).withMessageAttributeNames("All").withAttributeNames("All");
sqs.receiveMessageAsync(request, this);
```

Where `this` implement `AsyncHandler<ReceiveMessageRequest, ReceiveMessageResult>` my callback is never called.

I stepped through the code and the problem appears to be in this function

```
public Future<ReceiveMessageResult> receiveMessage(ReceiveMessageRequest rq,
                                                       AsyncHandler<ReceiveMessageRequest, ReceiveMessageResult> handler) {
        // only handle simple requests, because these are the settings we pre-fetch with
        boolean noAttributes = (rq.getAttributeNames() == null) || rq.getAttributeNames().isEmpty();
        boolean noMessageAttributesToRetrieve = (rq.getMessageAttributeNames() == null)
                || rq.getMessageAttributeNames().isEmpty();
        boolean bufferngEnabled = (config.getMaxInflightReceiveBatches() > 0)
                && (config.getMaxDoneReceiveBatches() > 0);
        if (noMessageAttributesToRetrieve && noAttributes && bufferngEnabled && (rq.getVisibilityTimeout() == null)) {
            QueueBufferCallback<ReceiveMessageRequest, ReceiveMessageResult> callback = null;
            if (handler != null) {
                callback = new QueueBufferCallback<ReceiveMessageRequest, ReceiveMessageResult>(handler, rq);
            }

            QueueBufferFuture<ReceiveMessageRequest, ReceiveMessageResult> future = receiveBuffer.receiveMessageAsync(
                    rq, callback);
            future.setBuffer(this);
            return future;
        } else {
            return realSqs.receiveMessageAsync(rq);
        }
    }
```

specifically in the if statement

`if (noMessageAttributesToRetrieve && noAttributes && bufferngEnabled && (rq.getVisibilityTimeout() == null))`

Inside of the if is where it sets the callback, if all the conditions aren't met it doesn't call the callback. But from looking at the code I can't see any reason why requesting any kind of attribute or buffering would cause the call back not to be called. This doesn't make any sense to me, so I'm curious what I'm doing wrong, or why requesting any attributes would cause the callback to not be called.